# Angular JS error - http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I keep getting the error mentioned in the title. I have tried reading Angular docs on the error and seems like I am going everything fine.

I have 3 modules App.js, planCtrl.js and gservice.js and attached them like below

**index.html**

```
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<!-- Google Libraries -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDvkISJD8ay_X92_2BJxoe1k15ICtGFf5o&libraries=places"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>

<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/planCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/gservice.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
var chaloApp = angular
     .module('chaloApp', [
        'planCtrl', 'gservice', 'ngCookies', 
        'ngRoute', 'ngMessages', 'ui.bootstrap'
    ]);
```

**plan.js**

```
var planCtrl = angular.module('planCtrl', ['gservice']);

planCtrl.controller('planController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', '$location', '$compile', '$uibModal', 'gservice', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $cookies, $location, $compile, $uibModal, gservice){
```

**gservice.js**

```
angular.module('gservice', [])
    .factory('gservice', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function($scope, $rootScope, $http){
```

Here is the full error if details are needed.

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=<div class="routePages ng-scope" ng-view="">copeProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%20%3C-%20gservice
at Error (native)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:6:416
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:43:7
at Object.d [as get] (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:40:270)
at https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:43:69
at d (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:40:270)
at e (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:41:1)
at Object.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:41:86)
at Object.$get (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:38:460)
at Object.invoke (https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0/angular.min.js:41:295)
```

Been struggling with this one for bit so appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you show the rest of the scripts that you're loading?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22routePages%20ng-scope%22%20ng-view%3D%22%22%3EcopeProvider%20%3C-%20$scope%20%3C-%20gservice

Comment: include gservice first.

Comment: have you included routes js file in the page? are all dependencies loaded?  sometimes it might also happen when you load first the routes before angular got loaded.

Comment: @LJ.Wizard - Just updated the index.html code to show rest of the scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in **index.html**:

```
<script src="js/gservice.js"></script>
<script src="js/planCtrl.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

This is because `planCtrl` depends on `gservice` and `chaloApp` depends on `planCtrl` and `gservice`, so you need to include them first.

Comment: Thanks, Luis. I am going to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include your `gservice.js` file first, as other modules depends on it:

```
<script src="js/gservice.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/planCtrl.js"></script>
```

**Edit**
Your error message indicates that the `$scope` provider can't be injected in your `gservice`.

You should only inject `$rootScope` in your service:

```
angular.module('gservice', [])
    .factory('gservice', ['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http)
```

Comment: I did that, but did not work.  I am creating a plunkr to show rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you change the name of your `gservice` factory to be different to that of your factory module. Having the same name can confuse things. It also looks like you're injecting your `gservice` module, into your `plan` controller module, when it should be injected into your `app` model.

Try the following changes:

**plan.js**

```
var planCtrl = angular.module('planCtrl', []);

planCtrl.controller('planController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', '$cookies', '$location', '$compile', '$uibModal', 'newGservice', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, $cookies, $location, $compile, $uibModal, newGservice){
```

**gservice.js**

```
angular.module('gservice', [])
    .factory('newGservice', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$http', function($scope, $rootScope, $http){
```

Comment: Thanks, LJ. Let me try that.